# Unable to add subview in main view on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

in my project, there are UIView and it have two buttons

i just want to add subview on main view on the click of second button

i am new in iOS so any one help me please

[image: my view screenshot given below]

Comment: Put some code that you have try.

Comment: How can we debug your issue without you showing us the code and any errors you are getting?

Comment: here is my code for add subview on second button click- (IBAction)history_btn:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 119, 320, 449); // Replacing with your dimensions
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
and it worked fine..i just want that when i clk on my first button this subview hidden on my mainView...@Nirav and @Simon sir please help me

Comment: @arun that code is unreadable. Never post code in comments. Edit your question to include the code and format it correctly with the provided tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on first Button Click Event just add secondView.hidden=Yes;
and more over create the global instance of the secondView